# Alignment issue with Bootstrap Nav & Flexbox Items at either end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having difficulty moving items on my Navbar to either end. At the moment I have this: 
[image: Navbar issue]

I would like to move the flag image next to the toggler button, it is only there when the breakpoint reaches the Navbar button size, 992px.

I'm sure the Bootstrap Stylesheet is aligning it using `justify-content: space-between;` I have tried using `align-self: flex-end !important;` on both flag and button as well as using `justify-content-end`

Codepen - https://codepen.io/jvern22/pen/gZjJBN

My Nav code;

```
  <div class="container container-navbar">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Website title</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-end" href="#"><img src="assets/img/spain.png" class="navbar-flag"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1" aria-controls="top-navbar-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">            
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=taketour"><?php echo $lang['nav_takeatour']; ?></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=websites"><?php echo $lang['nav_websites']; ?></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>        

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you tried grouping your `flag` and `button` elements inside a `div`? This will enforce those 2 items to stick together with `space-between`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap the flag and the navbar button within a div as shown in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/YdOKMB) or in the Code Snippet below:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height:100%; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  position:relative;
  font: 400 15px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-dark a {
  color: #aaa;
}

.bg-dark a:hover, .bg-dark a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
 line-height: 20px;
  padding-right: 12px!important;
  padding-left: 12px!important;
  padding-top: 10px!important;
  padding-bottom: 10px!important;
}

.navbar-flag {
  height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 2200px){

  .navbar-flag {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-no-bg" role="navigation">
    
      <div class="container container-navbar">     
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Website title</a>
        
        <div>
          <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-end" href="#"><img src="
https://i.imgur.com/TXhhmGb.png" class="navbar-flag"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1" aria-controls="top-navbar-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">            
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=taketour"><?php echo $lang['nav_takeatour']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=websites"><?php echo $lang['nav_websites']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=rates"><?php echo $lang['nav_rates']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=contactus"><?php echo $lang['nav_contact']; ?></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>        
        
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Or you can just change the `justify-content` property of the parent div from `space-between` to `flex-end` and add a `margin-right: auto` to the first `navbar-brand` as shown in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewl64/pen/EGexVR) or in the Code Snippet below:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height:100%; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
  position:relative;
  font: 400 15px "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a.navbar-brand:first-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
.bg-dark {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-dark a {
  color: #aaa;
}

.bg-dark a:hover, .bg-dark a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
 line-height: 20px;
  padding-right: 12px!important;
  padding-left: 12px!important;
  padding-top: 10px!important;
  padding-bottom: 10px!important;
}

.navbar-flag {
  height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 2200px){

  .navbar-flag {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-no-bg" role="navigation">
    
      <div class="container container-navbar">
      
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Website title</a>
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-end" href="#"><img src="
          https://i.imgur.com/TXhhmGb.png" class="navbar-flag"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1" aria-controls="top-navbar-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">            
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=taketour"><?php echo $lang['nav_takeatour']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=websites"><?php echo $lang['nav_websites']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=rates"><?php echo $lang['nav_rates']; ?></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="?page=contactus"><?php echo $lang['nav_contact']; ?></a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>        
        
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here is to just expand the first flex item so that it pushes all the other items to the right. This can be easily done by adding the following to your css:

```
.navbar-brand:first {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```